# Graphing on a region with integral

Tags: multivariable-calculus

[image: Graphing on a region with integral]
Can someone help me with this I am very lost in this

Comment: The answer is the volume of a "cylinder" of height $1$. (More precisely, say an $R$-cylinder; if $R$ is a hexagon, it is a hexagonal cylinder). But more importantly, are you comfortable with what is claimed in the first sentence, and can you visualize what would be the shape of that solid for a given $R$?

Answer (score 1):

You can interpret $\int_R f(x,y) dA$, with $f(x, y) = 1$ as the volume of a cylinder or [prism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prism_%28geometry%29) sitting on the x-y plane, with height equal to $1$, and whose top is "flat"  like the "bottom" which sits on the xy plane (so the is bottom bounded by the plane $z = 0$ and the top bounded by the plane $z = 1$, with sides perpendicular to the top and the bottom.)

If R is a circle, you have a 1-unit tall circular cylinder. If R is a square or rectangle, you have a rectangular solid prism (which you can visualize as a solid rectangular box). Whatever the *nice shape* of R on the x-y plane (assuming "nice" means a convex polygon of sorts), you'll have that short of shaped cylinder or prism with a "top" parallel to the x-y plane: a convex solid.

This section of the Wikipedia ***[article on prisms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prism_%28geometry%29#See_also)*** will help you to visualize these 3-dimensional objects.

Answer (score 0):

Well...exactly the same interpretation, I think...perhaps in the second case it is easier to see it is the volume of a straight box shaped as $\,R\,$ and with height $\,1\,$, but for this it is just the same, imo...oh, and of course: this is just
, numerically, the same as the area of the plane region $\,R\,$...:)

Comment: Can you tell me what it looks like and how you did it?

Comment: Just take the region R and form with it a three-dimensional body shaped exactly as $\,R\,$ but in space...like you "strech" region $\,R\,$ into $\,3D\,$....since the height is $\,1\,$ numerically you get, for this volume, the very same number as the area of $\,R\,$ :)